# Chip in a relay?

Tags: relay

I opened up the fuel pump relay in my car expecting to see a little electromagnet and contacts. What was there besides was a whole circuit board, complete with a chip. It reminded my of the dashboard dimmer in the same car which has a complex, 2-layer circuit board just to dim the dash lights.

Why would a relay have a circuit board and chip in it?

Just for reference its Volvo part number 9434225.

Comment: Do you have a photo?

Comment: @winny You can google the part number to get threads like this with photos: https://www.matthewsvolvosite.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9681&start=40

Comment: No, that’s your job.

Comment: @winny is right. You are not an EE.SE newbie and you should know better. We *require* effort from the asker to make his question complete and high quality, i.e. useful also for other people browsing the site.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Ok, I will just not use your site anymore. Sorry for wasting your valuable time.

Comment: Aside from CANbus intefacing etc, the contact was replaced by a hall effect sensor and a power transistor, which don't slowly burn away.

Comment: Time is valuable for everyone, not just *me*. I'm sorry to see you go, but if you don't agree on the very basic guidelines of this site, well it's your choice. I hope *sincerely* you find somewhere else the information you may seek in the future, but be aware that the high quality you find here has a price. If no one wanted to pay that price, this site wouldn't exist. Almost the only *real* reward (no, rep points are not that "real") knowledgeable users get from posting quality answers is that they know they are building something that can make the difference on the Internet landscape. ...

Comment: ... Here good answers aren't swamped in nonsense and crap like in most other electronics forum threads. Our "threads" are meant to last, and to achieve that we must follow at least some basic principles on which our community is built.

Answer (score 5):

> Why would a relay have a circuit board and chip in it?

A car fuel pump relay is a safety critical device and, should the car be involved in some form of accident, that relay should self-reset so as to not pump fuel onto the street. Therefore, as a typical example, the engine management system sends continual pulses to the relay in order to keep it activated and, should the engine stall or some other fault develop, the pulses will stop and the relay will quickly deactivate.

This needs a certain amount of electronics (as an overhead to process the pulse signal) and keep the relay closed. It's also possible that the relay may be activated by CAN bus and this needs electronic circuits for decoding the CAN bus transmission.

Answer (score 1):

Cars these days have centralized processing in the vehicle computer and localized electronics at the control/sensor end points. A signalling bus network is used to interconnect the car computer to these end points. So now a digital data packet can be sent to the fuel pump relay to turn on and off.

This scheme is used to reduce the total number of copper wires that have to be strung all over the vehicle saving considerably on manufacturing cost.